# ROS Code VideoCapture doesn't work on Intel NUC5i5MYBE

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, intel, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using Intel NUC5i5MYBE for my application.

I have my code for the **VideoCapture** from **USB Camera** and it is tested and working perfectly in my **Intel i5 PC**.
However I am using the same code in **INTEL NUC5i5MYBE** but I am getting few errors regarding VideoCapture.

The screenshorts of mode and the errors are attached below.

***The Code***

```
 #ifdef CAMERA_INTERFACE
 void *socket_server::display(void *ptr)
 {
uchar *buffer;
int bytes = 0;
int chkBytesRecv = 0;
int sendFlag = 0;
//VideoCapture cap(0);   
int socket = videoRemoteSocket;
int numBytesAvailable = 0;
unsigned char dataBuffer[200000] = {0};
unsigned char  *buffer1 = &dataBuffer[0];
FILE *in;
/*OpenCV Code*/

Mat img, imgGray;
img = Mat::zeros(480 , 640 , CV_8UC3);

int imgSize = img.total() * img.elemSize()  ;

if ( ! img.isContinuous() )
{
    img = img.clone();
    imgGray = img.clone();
}

cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 10); //start the video   

double fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video    

while(1)
{
    if(connectionVideoFormed == 1)
    {
    

    /* get a frame from camera */
    cap >> img;   
    //cout<<"inside display():"<< socket <<endl;
    //while (1)
    //{

    
    
    //sleep(5);

    vector<int> compression_params; //vector that stores the compression parameters of the image

    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY); //specify the compression technique

    compression_params.push_back(98); //specify the compression quality

    bool bSuccess = imwrite(jpegImage.c_str(), img, compression_params); //write the image to file


    /*****IF connection is there then only send data*************/

    
    //if(videoStremingOnOff == 1)
    //{ 
        
        in = fopen(jpegImage.c_str(),"rb");
        

        if(in != NULL)
        {
            

            fseek(in,0,SEEK_END);
            unsigned int size = ftell(in);
            unsigned char size_char = (unsigned char)size;
            unsigned int temp_size = htonl(size);

            fseek(in,0,SEEK_SET);       
            
            
            //cout<<"image size 1 = "<<size<<endl;
            //cout<<"image size 2 = "<<temp_size<<endl;
            
            //memset(buffer1,0,sizeof(buffer1));

            int byte_read=fread(buffer1, sizeof(unsigned char), size , in);
            
            
            if ((bytes = send(socket, &temp_size, 4, 0)) < 0)                   
            {

                cout<<"video_size sending failed"<<endl;
                connectionVideoFormed = 0;
                close(videoRemoteSocket);

            }
            else
            {
                //cout<<"video_size sending successful:"<<temp_size<<endl;

            }
            if ((bytes = send(socket, buffer1, size, 0)) < 0)

            {
                cout<< "video sending failed" <<endl;
                connectionVideoFormed = 0;
                close(videoRemoteSocket);
            }
            else
            {
                //cout<< "video sending successful"<<endl;


            }
            
            //bzero(&iptr[bytesToShift], ((sizeof(iptr))- bytesToShift));
            
        }
        fclose(in);         
        
    /*}
    else
    {
        //cout<<"Video streaming off"<<endl; 

    } */


    }
    usleep(100000);

}


 }
 #endif
```

**Error**

```
 [100%] Linking CXX executable /home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/server_node
 CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/src/server.cpp.o: In function `socket_server::display(void*)':
 server.cpp:(.text+0x180): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(int)'
 server.cpp:(.text+0x313): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::set(int, double)'
 server.cpp:(.text+0x327): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::get(int) const'
 server.cpp:(.text+0x347): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::operator>>(cv::Mat&)'
 server.cpp:(.text+0x685): undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture()'
 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
 dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/build.make:129: recipe for target '/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/server_node' failed
 make[2]: *** [/home/icrs/manipulator_proj/devel/lib/dynamixel_control/server_node] Error 1
 CMakeFiles/Makefile2:391: recipe for target 'dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/all' failed
 make[1]: *** [dynamixel_control/CMakeFiles/server_node.dir/all] Error 2
 Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
 make: *** [all] Error 2
 Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Below is my CMakeList.txt file content

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
 project(dynamixel_control)

 ## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
 add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

 ## Find catkin macros and libraries
 ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
 ## is used, also find other catkin packages
 find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
   roscpp  
   std_msgs
   cv_bridge
   image_transport
   message_generation
   sensor_msgs
 )
 find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)
 find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
 
 add_message_files(DIRECTORY msg
     FILES 
     cfg.msg
     vel.msg
     jcfg.msg
     soln.msg
     jvel.msg
     mode.msg
     traj.msg
     jtraj.msg
     velpos.msg
     singlegroup.msg
     thetas.msg
     nonik_cmds.msg
     joint_num.msg
     actuator_data.msg
     actuator_vel.msg
     actuator_pos.msg
     ik_stat.msg
     health_status.msg

 )
 generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
    std_msgs
 )
 ## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
 # find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)


 ## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
 ## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
 ## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
 # catkin_python_setup()

 ################################################
 ## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
 ################################################

 ## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
 ## package, follow these steps:
 ## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
 ##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
 ## * In the file package.xml:
 ##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
 ##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
 ##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
 ##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
 ##     * add a run_depend tag for "message_runtime"
 ## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
 ##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
 ##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
 ##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
 ##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
 ##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
 ##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
 ##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
 ##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)

 ## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
 # add_message_files(
 #   FILES
 #   Message1.msg
 #   Message2.msg
 # )

 ## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
 # add_service_files(
 #   FILES
 #   Service1.srv
 #   Service2.srv
 # )

 ## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
 # add_action_files(
 #   FILES
 #   Action1.action
 #   Action2.action
 # )

 ## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
 # generate_messages(
 #   DEPENDENCIES
 #   std_msgs
 #)

 ################################################
 ## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
 ################################################

 ## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
 ## package, follow these steps:
 ## * In the file package.xml:
 ##   * add a build_depend and a run_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
 ## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
 ##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
 ##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
 ##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
 ##     and list every .cfg file to be processed

 ## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder

 # generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(

 #   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
 #   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
 # )

 ###################################
 ## catkin specific configuration ##
 ###################################
 ## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
 ## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
 ## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
 ## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
 ## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
 ## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
 catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES dynamixel_control   
    CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs message_runtime
    DEPENDS EIGEN3
 #  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
 #  DEPENDS system_lib

   #CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES dynamixel_sdk
 )

 ###########
 ## Build ##
 ###########

 ## Specify additional locations of header files
 ## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
 include_directories(
   include
   ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIR}
 )
 link_directories(${catkin_LIBRARY_DIRS})
 ## Declare a C++ library
 add_library(#${PROJECT_NAME}
 #   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/dynamixel_control.cpp
   dynamixel_sdk
   src/packet_handler.cpp
   src/protocol1_packet_handler.cpp
   src/protocol2_packet_handler.cpp
   src/group_sync_read.cpp
   src/group_sync_write.cpp
   src/group_bulk_read.cpp
   src/group_bulk_write.cpp
   src/port_handler.cpp
   src/port_handler_linux.cpp
 )

 ## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
 ## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
 ## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
 add_dependencies(dynamixel_sdk ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}                     ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
 #add_dependencies(ik inversekinematics_generate_messages_cpp)

 ## Declare a C++ executable
 ## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
 ## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
 add_executable(dynamixel_control src/dynamixel_control.cpp)

 ## Rename C++ executable without prefix
 ## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
 ## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
 ## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
 target_link_libraries(dynamixel_control dynamixel_sdk ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

 ## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
 ## same as for the library above
 # add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}      ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

 ## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
 # target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
 #   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
 # )

 add_executable(Keyboard_input src/Keyboard_input.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(Keyboard_input dynamixel_sdk ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

 add_executable(server_node src/server.h src/server.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(server_node dynamixel_sdk
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  )
 add_executable(ik src/ik.cpp)
 target_link_libraries(ik dynamixel_sdk ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

 #add_dependencies(Keyboard_input ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS}      ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

 #############
 ## Install ##
 #############

 # all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
 # See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

 ## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
 ## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
 # install(PROGRAMS
 #   scripts/my_python_script
 #   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 # )

 ## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
 # install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
 #   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
 #   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
 #   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 # )
 install(TARGETS dynamixel_sdk
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
 )
 ## Mark cpp header files for installation
 # install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
 #   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
 #   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
 #   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
 # )
 install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
 )

 ## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
 # install(FILES
 #   # myfile1
 #   # myfile2
 #   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
 # )

 #############
 ## Testing ##
 #############

 ## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
 # catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_dynamixel_control.cpp)
 # if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
 #   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
 # endif()

 ## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
 # catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

CMakeList.txt

```
# toplevel CMakeLists.txt for a catkin workspace
# catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL TRUE)

# search for catkin within the workspace
set(_cmd "catkin_find_pkg" "catkin" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
execute_process(COMMAND ${_cmd}
  RESULT_VARIABLE _res
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE _out
  ERROR_VARIABLE _err
  OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
  ERROR_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)
if(NOT _res EQUAL 0 AND NOT _res EQUAL 2)
  # searching fot catkin resulted in an error
  string(REPLACE ";" " " _cmd_str "${_cmd}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Search for 'catkin' in workspace failed (${_cmd_str}): ${_err}")
endif()

# include catkin from workspace or via find_package()
if(_res EQUAL 0)
  set(catkin_EXTRAS_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${_out}/cmake")
  # include all.cmake without add_subdirectory to let it operate in same scope
  include(${catkin_EXTRAS_DIR}/all.cmake NO_POLICY_SCOPE)
  add_subdirectory("${_out}")

else()
  # use either CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH explicitly passed to CMake as a command line argument
  # or CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH from the environment
  if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH)
    if(NOT "$ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}" STREQUAL "")
      string(REPLACE ":" ";" CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH $ENV{CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    endif()
  endif()

  # list of catkin workspaces
  set(catkin_search_path "")
  foreach(path ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
    if(EXISTS "${path}/.catkin")
      list(FIND catkin_search_path ${path} _index)
      if(_index EQUAL -1)
        list(APPEND catkin_search_path ${path})
      endif()
    endif()
  endforeach()

  # search for catkin in all workspaces
  set(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE TRUE)
  find_package(catkin QUIET
   NO_POLICY_SCOPE
    PATHS ${catkin_search_path}
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH NO_CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH)
      unset(CATKIN_TOPLEVEL_FIND_PACKAGE)

  if(NOT catkin_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "find_package(catkin) failed. catkin was neither found in the workspace nor in the                      CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH. One reason may be that no ROS setup.sh was sourced before.")
   endif()
 endif()

 catkin_workspace()
```

Kindly suggest us any solution for this issue.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281328/ros-code-videocapture-doesn%27t-work-on-intel-nuc5i5mybe/) by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2018-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This points to some missing dependencies. Are you sure you have the dependencies, especially opencv, installed?

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2018-01-31**:
I didn't install Opencv separately, I installed ROS Kinetic.
Do I need to install OpenCv separately???

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-01-31**:
Well, but which packages...
If you install e.g. `ros-kinetic-cv-bridge` will automatically install `opencv3`. Check out the [ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/opencv3) for more Details. Also, `rosdep` could help you in resolving dependencies, as Long as they are specified correctly.

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2018-01-31**:
hi mig

we installed cv_bridge and opencv3.4 along with **ros-kinetic** .
we found that the same code is running on different PC  installed with opencv2.4.9 so we also installed opencv2.4.9 in our **intel NUC** board however the result remain unchanged (same error)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
@Radeshwar: ROS comes with a specific version of OpenCV. Installing OpenCV yourself is not recommended (until you get more comfortable with all of this).

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2018-01-31**:
hi gvdhoorn

we tried with default version of opencv  that comes with ros-kinetic but we are getting the Videocapture error . so we wanted to try different version of opencv ,however the result was same(videocapture error)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
Unless you overwrote the ROS distributed version or overrode the version found by `CMake` it might not have used the parallel installated versions.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-31**:
Please add the contents of your `CMakeLists.txt` to your original question. Please use the *Preformatted Text* button to format it properly and *please* don't include all the comments. They are not needed.

**Comment by [Radeshwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/32196/radeshwar/) on 2018-02-01**:
I have added my CMakeList.txt file content to my question.
I have not removed comments because I am not sure whether I have commented any required commands which is necessary.
Kindly go through.
Thanks.